# Django - Non-verbose ways to save POST data

Tags: django

I'm simply wondering whether there is a better way to take from data and write it to a database. The 'standard' way feels a little verbose to me. So my question is simply how to rewrite this in a less redundant way. I mean it works, but I feel like this isn't the 'correct' way...

```
def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        ticket = Ticket.objects.get(id = ticket_id)
        comment = Comment()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if 'solve_comment' in request.POST:
                ticket.state_id = 5
                text = request.POST['solve_comment']
                comment.text = text
                comment.comment_type = "solving_note"
                comment.content_type = ContentType.objects.get(id=114)
                comment.object_id = ticket.id
                comment.created_by_id = request.user.id
                comment.save()
                ticket.save()
```

The issues with this is if there is say, 5+inputs in a form which creates this massive wall of code. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Yes - Thats what [`ModelForms`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) are for...

Comment: I see. Is there no other way to shorten standard forms?

Comment: You could do `Comment(**request.POST.copy())`, but not very safe..You could run into a bunch of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [CreateView generic view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview). There's also an [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView) for updating existing objects.

In my experience, it's fairly rare to not be able to use a generic view for something in Django, and for form handling they're generally the quickest way to implement something.

Comment: You're welcome. If this has answered your question, please don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Yup, I just had to wait a bit. Cheers.